# Using rhc tools OpenShift

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I do not understand the uses for the commands `ssh` or `git-clone` in the `rhc` tool. If I try to connect via ssh I have to use a client like PuTTY and if I like to clone a project I have to use the GitBash on Windows. My question is, when I use the commands above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use those commands if you have an ssh client, or git client that is accessible via your command line in windows.  So if you can open up your cmd prompt, and type "ssh" or "git" and it works, then you can use the rhc ssh, and rhc git-clone commands.  Mostly they are useful for Unix, Linux, and OS X, but with some configuration you should be able to do it from windows also.